# What are the possible reasons that accuracies in 5-folds cross validation is largely different in CNN?

Tags: tensorflow, validation, conv-neural-network, variance, k-fold

I am a novice in neural networks. I just started a project using CNN, and this project uses a dataset with 2 million cases, which was generated from the same covariance matrix.
When I tried 5-fold cross-validation, the accuracies from 4 validations are reported around .9. However, one validation reported only .1 of accuracy. I cannot understand why it happens. I think because all data was generated from the same covariance matrix, accuracies of all validations should be all low or all high. I made the folds using train_test_split function below:

```
for I in range(0, n_folds):
    t_x, val_x, t_y, val_y = train_test_split(flat_act_list, flat_act_list_T, test_size=0.2, shuffle=False)
```

Did I make some mistakes?
And would someone please explain when this situation (huge variance of accuracy for each validation) could happen?

Answer (score 0):

Your dataset seems to be ordered. Try changing `shuffle=False` to `shuffle=True` and your cross-validations should be closer together.